# Is DeviceID or Contactkey use when MobilePush sends token to APNS/FCM?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I'm trying to figure out which is used between DeviceID and Contactkey when MobilePush sends token to APNS or FCM

What I understand about the steps in sending push notification,

1. SDK requests System Token and Device Token from each Device OS
2. Device OS request needed token value to PNS(APNS/FCM)
3. Device OS return the token value to SDK
4. SDK sends token value to marketing cloud
5. Marketing cloud uses token value to send Push Notification via PNS(APNS/FCM)

So my question is in the 5th step above, when marketing cloud requests PNS(APNS/FCM) to send push notification, which one is used for token value? DeviceID or Contactkey?

I'm trying to find an official documentation for this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neither.  Your Device/Contact Registration is a collection of values that include your push token, Device ID, Contact Key, et al.

There is only 1 value that can be used to send a push to a device: the push token.  How that token is resolved is up to you -- you create segmented audience lists for the push messages.  You might send to all users of the application.  You might target a specific user.  You might do something in between, but Google/Apple only understand the push token.

Comment: Hi thank you for this information! May I ask if I can be referred to any documentation so I can share with my coworker? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks